# React: Cerrar Modal en componente padre desde componente hijo en componente funcional

Tags: reactjs

Necesito cerrar la modal del componente padre desde el componente hijo, ambos son componentes funcionales.
Cómo podría hacerlo?

**Componente Padre**

```
                    const ComponentePadre = () => {
                    const [show, setShow] = useState(); 
                    
                    const openModal = () => {
                        setShow(true);
                    };

                    const closeModal = () => {
                        setShow(false);
                    };

                    return  (
                        <>
                        <Modal show={show} onHide={closeModal}>
                            <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>
                            <>
                                <ComponenteHijo />
                            </>
                            </Modal.Body>
                        </Modal>
                        </>
                    );
                    };

                    export default ComponentePadre;
```

**Componente hijo**

```
            const ComponenteHijo = () => {

            return (
                <>
                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger">cerrar Modal En Componente Padre</button>
                </div>
                </>
            ) ;
            };

            export default ComponenteHijo;
```

Me ahorro las importaciones, aunque posiblemente deba importar alguna función al componente hijo, es posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes pasar tu funcion closeModal hacia tu componente hijo, sigue con estos pasos:

**Componente Padre**

- Debes establecer un valor inicial a tu estado del modal

  ```
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  ```
- Ahora debes pasar la funcion `closeModal` como prop a tu componente hijo para actualizar el estado

  ```
  <ComponenteHijo closeModal={closeModal}/>
  ```

**Component Hijo**

```
const ComponenteHijo = ({ closeModal }) => {
   return (
      <div>
         <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => closeModal}>cerrar Modal En Componente Padre</button>
      </div>
    );
 };
```

- En El Component Hijo recibes la prop y la ejecutas en el evento onClick del button

Comment: Genial! funciona! muchas gracias!!